# Chaincode instantiation failing silently

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I tried installing and instantiating the `chaincode_example02` chaincode on the network I brought up by modifying the byfn script from [build your first network](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html). I am using 2 orgs with 1 peer each. I renamed the orgs.

The peer containers are coming up and I am able to install the chaincode on the peers of both the orgs. When I am instantiating, the chaincode container comes up. The command does not return any error.

But I am unable to query the chaincode. I am unable to find the chaincode in `peer chaincode list --instantiated -C mychannel`.

I have tried running the byfn script without any modifications and I was able to complete the end to end test.

peer log

```
2019-08-22 08:46:29.062 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 038 Failed connecting to {localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-08-22 08:46:29.063 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 039 Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]}]
2019-08-22 08:46:29.063 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 03a Failed obtaining connection: could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]}]
2019-08-22 08:46:29.064 UTC [deliveryClient] try -> WARN 03b Got error: could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]}] , at 1 attempt. Retrying in 1s
2019-08-22 08:46:30.099 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 03c [][276fe51c] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
2019-08-22 08:46:30.103 UTC [lscc] executeInstall -> INFO 03d Installed Chaincode [mycc] Version [1.0] to peer
2019-08-22 08:46:30.103 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 03e [][276fe51c] Exit chaincode: name:"lscc"  (4ms)
2019-08-22 08:46:30.103 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 03f unary call completed grpc.service=protos.Endorser grpc.method=ProcessProposal grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.5:54174 grpc.code=OK grpc.call_duration=5.100738ms
2019-08-22 08:46:30.200 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> INFO 040 [ssidchannel][293c34bf] Entry chaincode: name:"lscc"
2019-08-22 08:46:30.220 UTC [chaincode.platform.golang] GenerateDockerBuild -> INFO 041 building chaincode with ldflagsOpt: '-ldflags "-linkmode external -extldflags '-static'"'
2019-08-22 08:46:33.066 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 042 Failed connecting to {localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]} , error: context deadline exceeded
2019-08-22 08:46:33.066 UTC [ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 043 Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]}]
2019-08-22 08:46:33.066 UTC [deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 044 Failed obtaining connection: could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]}]
```

orderer logs

```
2019-08-22 08:46:16.512 UTC [orderer.commmon.multichannel] newChain -> INFO 00b Created and starting new chain ssidchannel
2019-08-22 08:46:16.518 UTC [common.deliver] Handle -> WARN 00c Error reading from 192.168.0.5:47044: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-08-22 08:46:16.518 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00d streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Deliver grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.5:47044 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=55.824801ms
2019-08-22 08:46:23.203 UTC [orderer.common.broadcast] Handle -> WARN 00e Error reading from 192.168.0.5:47060: rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled
2019-08-22 08:46:23.203 UTC [comm.grpc.server] 1 -> INFO 00f streaming call completed grpc.service=orderer.AtomicBroadcast grpc.method=Broadcast grpc.peer_address=192.168.0.5:47060 error="rpc error: code = Canceled desc = context canceled" grpc.code=Canceled grpc.call_duration=22.774639ms
```

chaincode container logs

```
Aval = 100, Bval = 200
2019-08-22 08:20:10.458 UTC [shim] chatWithPeer -> ERRO 001 Received error from server, ending chaincode stream: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
receive failed
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.chatWithPeer
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:362
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim.Start
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim/chaincode.go:156
main.main
        /chaincode/input/src/fabric-samples/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/chaincode_example02.go:195
runtime.main
        /opt/go/src/runtime/proc.go:201
runtime.goexit
        /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333
Error starting Simple chaincode: receive failed: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing
```

Answer (score 1):

The chaincode container after spawning was getting connected to a different network than that of the peers and orderers. I changed the `CORE_VM_DOCKER_HOSTCONFIG_NETWORKMODE` property in the `peer-base.yaml` file to match the network in the `docker-compose-cli.yaml` file to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
ERRO 044 Failed obtaining connection: could not connect to any of the endpoints: [{localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]}]
```

Its clear indication that peer is not able to connect the orderer

[OrdererMSP] >> why this is present in the list of orderer endpoint?
 I assume that you have done something wrong

`[{localhost:7050 [OrdererMSP]}]` <<< wrong representation

Please paste here peer manifest, orderer manifest, and configtx.yaml

In order to investigate the issue